# progress bar freezes drupal quicktabs

Tags: drupal, module, progress-bar

i using quicktabs in my site and active Ajax load for any tabs
now when click on tabs progress bar loaded and show content tabs but progress bar freezes and appear

usually progress bar should be hidden

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Quicktabs issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/quicktabs), specifically the "[Progress bar doesn't go away when view selected](https://drupal.org/node/363005)" issue. <strike>Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a fix yet, but I'm sure they'd appreciate a patch. :)</strike>

UPDATE: After reading all the comments, it sounds like the issue may or may not be fixed in the latest dev release. There seem to be conflicting reports.